# Resolving "Warning in if (stri_startswith_fixed(body, "{")) { :..." when using the plumber library in R

Tags: r, plumber

Currently getting this error when I make a POST request in plumber:

```
Warning in if (stri_startswith_fixed(body, "{")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
Warning in if (stri_startswith_fixed(qs, "?")) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

This is what my function looks like:

```
#' Get results from Two Sample t-test
#' @serializer unboxedJSON
#' @param group:character The group col you would like to group data by
#' @param variable:character The variable you would like to be compared between groups
#' @post /twosamplettest/<group>/<variable>
function(req, group, variable) {
    data_as_df <- fromJSON(req$postBody)

    results <- t.test(get(variable) ~ get(group), data=data_as_df)

    group_mean_df <- extractGroupsAndMeansFromTTestResults(results)

    test_results <- list(pvalue=results$p.value, group_stats=as.data.frame(group_mean_df)))

    test_results
}
```

Even something as simple as this gives the same warning:

```
#' @post /test
function(message){
  "Testerino"
}
```

The request gets a valid response and everything is all good except for that ugly warning message that shows up in the console for every request made.

Any ideas on how to resolve it?

Comment: Not reproducible. I suspect it comes from the code in `extractGroupsAndMeansFromTTestResults` but we have no way to understand further. You haven't offered any results from debugging efforts. You might try searching SO for examples of debugging techniques.

Comment: I think the error lies in the request postBody so I've tried various parsing techniques with no avail. Also tried collapsing the postBody into a single line string thinking there was an issue there, but the warning persists.
There aren't any if statements or anything in that extractGroups method and the warning was there before that point.

Comment: added simple post method that still leads to the same warning

Comment: Posting function definitions that throw warnings without a use case that demonstrates 1) how to call and 2) what data gives a warning is a a pretty useless SO question. If you can reproduce it with a library function then perhaps you should send that full example to the package maintainer. See `?maintainer`

Comment: Cool, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Turns it out it had to do with the JSON being used in the postBody. If the JSON contains unescaped tabs or newlines, the warning is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There is an [issue](https://github.com/rstudio/plumber/issues/270) closed on the plumber repository, this should not happen anymore in the latest version 1.0.0.